# Unable to run wcf service in localhost

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I am developing wcf application and i am trying to run it locally. I am developing simple application to update some data in database. Below is my code.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOpportunity
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool updateOpportunity(opportunityActivity obj);
}
[DataContract]
public class opportunityActivity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityStatus { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityserviceType { get; set; }
}

public class Opportunity : IOpportunity
{
    public bool updateOpportunity(opportunityActivity obj)
    {
        Test_ROLSP_DB_V1Entities dbobject = new Test_ROLSP_DB_V1Entities();
        bool isexists = (from c in dbobject.OpportunityActivityDetails where c.RSOpportunityID == obj.opportunityID select c).Any();
        if(isexists)
        { 
             using (var db = new Test_ROLSP_DB_V1Entities())
             {
                OpportunityActivityDetail oppObject =(from c in db.OpportunityActivityDetails where c.RSOpportunityID==obj.opportunityID select c).FirstOrDefault();
                oppObject.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
                oppObject.ActivityStatus = obj.opportunityStatus;
                oppObject.ServiceType = obj.opportunityserviceType;
                int isupdated=db.SaveChanges();
                if(isupdated==1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
             }

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I can run above solution without any error. Below is the web.config code.

```
<services>
  <service name="RayaSoapService.Opportunity">
    <endpoint address="" contract="RayaSoapService.IOpportunity" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

When i run the above code i get directory listings
[image]

When i click on opportunity.svc i get the below error.
The type 'RayaSoapService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

I am new to WCF. May i know why above error occurs? May i know am i following right way to run the above application? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-application

Comment: http://code-zest.blogspot.sg/2013/10/different-ways-to-run-wcf-services.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a WCF service application, Service1.svc creates automatically. If you change name of this file, the name Service1 remains in svc file. Open Opportunity.svc with Notepad and change Service1 to Opportunity.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service1" CodeBehind="Opportunity.svc.cs" %>
```

This is a .NET bug.

Comment: may i know how can i give xml input to the above service?

Answer (score 0):

change naming in Your opportunity.svc file path

```
 <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RayaSoapService.Opportunity" CodeBehind="Opportunity.svc.cs" %>
```

There is bit more naming to do, if you change default name in WCF service